# Bash dealing with subprompts in programs

Tags: bash, shell

What way can one deal with subprompts in a program when using bash scripting?

For example:
The program mpsyt has a sub prompt system for running, here is a picture of it.
[image: sub-program]

So In bash I have been trying to use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
newline="\n"
set -x
mpsyt=(mpsyt $1) &
sleep 1
echo $2$newline | $mpsyt
```

But i cannot figure how to either have a variable as a program and pass that strings via stdin or send keys to the process.

Comment: Take a look at the [expect utility](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/).

Comment: So why `echo -e "$2\n" | mpsyt $1` doesn't work?